# Add support for secure Wikipedia pages to Onebox

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, onebox

I use HTTPS Everywhere in Firefox, and so all of my requests to Wikipedia (among other sites) get automatically re-directed by the browser to their secure site.  This gives me headache when I want to post an article to chat, and have it Oneboxed.

Onebox works fine for me on regular Wikipedia links like this one:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange

But fails to recognize the secure pages like this one:

- https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Stack_Exchange

The only ways around this for me are to either disable Wikipedia redirection in HTTPS Everywhere, or search for and load the page in IE and copy the link from there.

Is it SSL that breaks the Onebox, or does Onebox just not recognize addresses from the secure site?  If the latter, can a simple change be made to add this in?

Comment: Sidenote:  Why do SO & SF have Wiki pages, but not SU?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it SSL that breaks the Onebox, or does Onebox just not recognize addresses from the secure site?  If the latter, can a simple change be made to add this in?

Yes.

Comment: Yes to which?  I'm guessing the `status-completed` tag means "Yes, the change can be (and has been) made."?

Comment: @Iszi: You're guessing correctly :)

Comment: Tested and confirmed!  Thanks for the quick turnaround!

Comment: @Iszi I have tested it with https youtube links, but the Onebox doesn't appear.

Comment: Don't know if they ever implemented it for HTTPS YouTube, but Wiki has been broken recently, too.

Comment: @balpha Wikipedia doesn't require the `secure.` subdomain anymore. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/) works, but fails to onebox.

Comment: Has this broken again? http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4690238#4690238

Comment: It's broken again.