# Secure Wiki Oneboxes don't link to secure Wikipedia pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

Thank you very much for [adding support for secure Wikipedia pages in Onebox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82029/add-support-for-secure-wikipedia-pages-to-onebox).  However, I've noticed that secure Wiki links get converted to normal links when they're Oneboxed.  Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it oneboxed, you have to live with the HTTP link. When clicking on the title of the Wikipedia onebox, the user can expect to get taken to the regular Wikipedia page.

By the way, what's the point? The reason you gave for your [original request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82029/add-support-for-secure-wikipedia-pages-to-onebox) was that

> all of my requests to Wikipedia (among other sites) get automatically re-directed by the browser to their secure site

– so why in the world does it even matter to you what version of the link is there?

Comment: I'm more curious as to why I "have to live with the HTTP link"?  Is it that much more difficult to maintain the same link that was used to refer to the article in the first place?

Comment: @Iszi: ad 1) I answered that above -- if somebody clicks on the title of the onebox, they rightfully expect to be taken to the regular Wikipedia page. If the only difference was `https://` vs. `http://` I wouldn't care as much, but it's a totally different domain and a totally different path. ad 2) No, but thanks for assuming that the only reason we do stuff in certain ways is just to save work. It would actually have been *easier* to maintain the same link. But that wasn't an option.

Comment: @lszi, balpha's good explanation about the domain aside: some workplaces (sadly) [have HTTPS blocked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83400/how-to-login-to-so-if-https-is-blocked). (I doubt those allow to use chat, but well, it *might* still be another reason not to enforce HTTPS to sites such as Wikipedia?)

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed, presumably with [the update to support the new-style HTTPS Wikipedia URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148273/preview-new-https-wikipedia-links-in-chat/164715#164715). If you enter a link like `https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow` in chat, it will now link to the HTTPS version, as desired.

Comment: Yeah, once Wikipedia moved away from their obscure HTTPS links, this wasn't really an issue anymore.