# Make chat onebox HTTPS links

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox, ssl

When I paste a link like http://www.xkcd.com/975 on chat, it promptly oneboxes the comic. However if I post the HTTPS version of that https://www.xkcd.com/975 it doesn't. This is true for all other oneboxable links from sites that let you access through HTTPS like YouTube.

Can we get HTTPS links oneboxed as well?

Comment: Seems to be the generic version of: [Add support for secure Wikipedia pages to Onebox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82029/add-support-for-secure-wikipedia-pages-to-onebox)

Comment: @awoodland ... where [Secure Wiki Oneboxes don't link to secure Wikipedia pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82342/secure-wiki-oneboxes-dont-link-to-secure-wikipedia-pages) shouldn't stay unmentioned

Comment: I'm not asking to convert links to HTTPS for me. I'm just asking to onebox them if I paste them as HTTPS. I don't mind if they are changed to HTTP when oneboxed. I think wikipedia is the only site that actually uses a different domain for SSL, so it's just a matter of taking the "s" out (currently I do this manually, but if I could skip that need... :)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Even Wikipedia doesn't use a separate domain anymore.

Comment: How is this still broken? This is not just a feature request, it's a damn bug!

Comment: Oh great, now we need to get pest control on the job!

Comment: Especially now that SE sites, such as Stack Overflow, support HTTPS - there will be a lot of question links with HTTPS...

Comment: Related, specific to xkcd: [XKCD oneboxing over HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210585/xkcd-oneboxing-over-https)