# Add Instragram oneboxing to chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

If you paste a link to an Instragram photo in chat, it is merely a link.  It doesn't become the image, or become an embedded Instagram dealy.  It'd be nice if it was oneboxed, and since Instagram supports embedding, I'd expect it to be relatively easy.

Comment: Image links are already shown in chat as images. Can you not get the direct link from instagram?

Comment: Is instagram used that much?

Comment: already exist: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=1981421#1981421

Comment: @rene Is there some trick to it?  I just pasted an instagram link in chat and nothing special happened.  This question was the first one on MSE about oneboxing instagram, so I don't know where to look for documentation.

Comment: Please post the link [here](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/651/sandbox)

Comment: @rene [Done](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3400368#3400368)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is due to me pasting an https link to chat.  Oneboxing does not support https, and chat doesn't try to help out by trying to onebox a http version of the link.

Comment: existing feature request http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111493/make-chat-onebox-https-links