# Preview new HTTPS Wikipedia links in chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, onebox

In chat, Wikipedia links normally get oneboxed. A while ago, support for secure Wikipedia links (`https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/`) was added: [Add support for secure Wikipedia pages to Onebox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82029/add-support-for-secure-wikipedia-pages-to-onebox).

However, Wikipedia now uses a new HTTPS URL scheme, the same as the HTTP link except with `https:` instead of `http:`. For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia oneboxing will accept the new-style HTTPS links from the next chat build on.